# From which HD wallet node is the private key in ethereum generated from?

Tags: wallets, private-key, keymanagement

I know how to generate a valid mnemonic and a valid address associated with that mnemonic. However I'm unsure how to generate a private key in ethereum. In Bitcoin, the [master node](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/raw/master/bip-0032/derivation.png) is where you'd get the private key (sometimes called the master private key)

However in ethereum, it seems that generation is kept very straight (the path is a standard "m/44'/60'/0'/0" and it seems that ethereum wallets do not take advantage of more than one account or in some cases more than one address.

Therefore, which node is the private key generated from? The root node and the child node in the path have different extended private keys?

Tag on question, how can I format the extended private key so it is not extended anymore?

Comment: hi @arshbot n this link help https://auth0.com/blog/an-introduction-to-ethereum-and-smart-contracts-part-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this github issue page](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bip39/issues/67#issuecomment-368271563) it turns out the answer is the private key is not generated as part of the node structure but instead the result of HMACing the first 32 bytes of the the entropy. An example below

```
import hdkey from 'ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey';
import ethwallet from 'ethereumjs-wallet';
import ethtx from 'ethereumjs-tx';
import bip39 from 'bip39';

const mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic();
console.log(`Mnemonic: ${mnemonic}`);
const root = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic));
const derivedNode = root.derivePath("m/44'/60'/0'/0");
const address = this.generateAddress(derivedNode);
console.log(`Private Key: ${root._hdkey.privateKey.toString('hex')}`);
```

The [actual private key generation](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/hdkey/blob/c076d89dfcd7a2205b27d7d80195890f71e87969/lib/hdkey.js#L170) occurs in hdkey